# what's the part of speech for "before"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am learning English recently. Here is a sentence I am confused of:

```
Before going to bed, she assure herself that the door was locked.
```

May I ask what the part of speech is for "before" here? I think it's a preposition because it connects gerund, "going". I am not sure if my thought is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a preposition. It starts a propositional phrase (because the gerund acts as the noun)
Its an adverbial phrase because it modifies the verb - answering the question **when**
Another simple example is:

*"I wash before eating."*

Answer (score 0):

"Before" is a preposition, but note that:
"before going to bed" is an adverbial phrase of time.
"before" is a preposition and "going to bed" is a complement to the preposition.